# Laravel hasManyThrough a different model

Tags: php, laravel

I have this situation: `Parent` and `Student` models are in many-to-many relationship, each of them `belongsTo()` the `User` model. `Branch` has many `Student` through `User` (`hasManyThrough(Student::class, User::class);`). I need to establish a relationship like that with `Parent` also: `hasManyThrough(Parent::class, User::class);` But the problem is `branch_id` in `users` table is nullable for parents. So I can't fetch the parents under a branch. I have to fetch those parents, whose students are under current branch. How can I get `Branch` to have many `Parent`s through the `Student`s of that `Branch`?

Here are some of my failed attempts of solving it. within the `parents()` method in `Branch.php`:

```
return \App\Parent::has('students.user.branch', $this)->get();
```

Didn't work. I know it isn't supposed to work. Next:

```
return \App\Parent::whereHas('students', function($query){
    $query->where() // stuck here. something could have been done here
})->get();
```

I even tried to filter the parents collection, but unfortunately, it was only returning the first parent in the collection:

```
return \App\Parent::all()->filter(function($parent){
        foreach($this->students as $student){
            foreach($student->parents as $currentParent){
                return $parent->id == $currentParent->id;
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: there is no relationship between parent and branch but you have relationship between Student and branch and student has relation with branch and parent, right?

Comment: Exactly.........

Comment: And Student model have the related function of the branch?

Comment: Student directly does not have it, but User has it

Comment: can you paste something by which I can get Idea that your user table and these number of column and student table have these many columns?

Comment: @DsRaj, what do you need? Schema?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172948/discussion-between-dsraj-and-eisenheim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested `whereHas`

```
return \App\Parent::whereHas('students', function($query) use ($branchId){
        $query->whereHas('user', function($subQu) use ($branchId){
            $subQu->where('branch_id','=',$branchId);
        });
})->with('students','students.user','students.user.branch')->get();
```